# Dynamic LINQ - Unable to convert between GUID and string

Tags: c#, linq

I am dynamically building a LINQ statement. The LINQ statement that I'm building is used purely for the WHERE clause.

```
string[] values = GetPropertyValues(); 
string propertyName = GetPropertyName();

string clause = string.Empty;
if (values.Length > 0)
  clause = propertyName + "==\"" + values[0] + "\"";
```

From what I can tell, my LINQ query looks correct. But when it gets executed, I receive an error that says:

*Operator '==' incompatible with operand types 'Guid?' and 'String'*

How do I remedy this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: Would you provide the sample data for values and propertyName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the property returned by GetPropertyName() is of type Guid  (I guess from the error), but you are trying to compare it to the contents of values[0] which you are declaring as a string.

Dynamic Linq lets you define parameters in your where clause so you can do

```
string clause = propertyName + "= @1";
LambdaExpression expr = Dynamic.ParseLambda( typeof(YourType), typeof(bool), clause, values[0]);
```

where `YourType` is the type of the item in the source `IQueryable`. So, for example if your source query was `IQueyable<Customer>` then `YourType` would be `Customer`. This will work no matter what the type of the property indicated by `propertyName` is.

When it does its parsing, Dynamic Linq figures out what the type arguments of the lambda expression should be using reflection on `YourType` and `propertyName`. The lambda expression you get is what you should use as the parameter of the `.Where()` extension method.

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer (although it's worth mentioning that the `Where` extension method also supports named parameters, so there is no need to call this static method). The actual difference between what OP is doing and this (that I would like to point out) is that *value* in this case doesn't have to be a string anymore; it can be an actual `Guid` instance. In that case, `GetPropertyValues()` would need to return actual values, not their string representations.

Comment: Quite right. GetPropertyValues would need to be of type object[] not string[].

Answer (score 8):

Works for me without parameter

```
"Id.Equals(Guid(\"D243372F-7ED0-40E6-B93D-6165F7521C29\"))"
```

With "Value" doesn't work. Error apear

> "{No property or field 'Value' exists in type 'Guid' (at index 3)}"

Answer (score 5):

For GUID comparison with dynamic linq use query properties and the Equals() method like in the provided sample.

```
var items = new[]
            {
                new { Id = Guid.Empty },
                new { Id = Guid.NewGuid() },
                new { Id = Guid.NewGuid() }
            };

var result = items.AsQueryable()
    .Where("Id.Equals(@0)", Guid.Empty)
    .Any();
```

Answer (score 3):

For a nullable value, something like this would work:

```
clause = "Id.Value.ToString()==\"a\""; /* Id is of type Guid? */
```

but it's obviously a rather specific case.

The [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) by Albahari might be a better solution altogether.

Comment: Maybe GetPropertyName() return a non-string object. So I guess it should be string propertyName = GetPropertyName().ToString();

Comment: @Love: I think that it actually returns the property name in a string form (`"Id"`, for example). That's basically what you need to build a dynamic `where` clause (to compare a value of a certain property to a different value). But when dynamic LINQ compiles the expression, it cannot compare the value of `Id` (which is a `Nullable<Guid>`) to a `String`.

Comment: You just saved my day. I can go with my kids for a picnic now :D

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to pass guid as a parameter, you can use that for string and guid comparison:

```
clause = "Id.Value.Equals(Guid(\"" + values[0] + "\"))";
```

That is works.

...Or that is in your example:

```
clause = propertyName + ".Value.Equals(\"" + values[0] + "\")";
```